# Notepad++ Find all instances of all caps words starting with underscore and convert to Proper Case

Tags: notepad++, regex, find-and-replace

Using Notepad++, I'm looking to find all words with ALL CAPS starting with underscore and to convert them to proper case.

Example 1,

```
Find:
DimCalendarDay_DATE

Replace with:
DimCalendarDay_Date
```

Example 2,

```
Find:
DimCalendarDay_YEAR_PERIOD_DAY

Replace with:
DimCalendarDay_Year_Period_Day
```

Example 3,

```
Find:
First_Day

Replace with:
First_Day
```

I already have entered the following within my Notepad++ search ad replace criteria:

```
Find what:  [_]\w*[A-Z]\w*[A-Z]\w* 
Replace with:  \L \u \1
```

However, the above regex replaces my found text with nothing.

Please advise...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(_[A-Z])([A-Z]*)(?![A-Z])`
- Replace with: `\u$1\L$2`
- *check Match case*
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
(_[A-Z])    # group 1, an underscore followed by a capital
([A-Z]*)    # group 2, 0 or more capitals
(?![A-Z])   # negative lookahead, make sure we haven't capital after
```

**Replacement:**

```
\u$1        # uppercased the content of group 1 (i.e. the first letter)
\L$2        # lowercased the content of group 2 (i.e. the rest of the match)
```

**Given:**

```
DimCalendarDay_DATE
DimCalendarDay_YEAR_PERIOD_DAY
First_Day
```

**Result for given example:**

```
DimCalendarDay_Date
DimCalendarDay_Year_Period_Day
First_Day
```

**Screen capture:**

[image]

Comment: Excellent!  Perfectly addresses my question!

Comment: @Toto but if I want to find only the words that starts with a capital letter ?

Comment: @JustMe: `\b[A-Z]\w+`